# Seleccionar option select y enviar dato en input conforme a la opcion seleccionada para que entre a una funcion diferente

Tags: angular

Tengo un `select` de 27 opciones y un `input`:

Dependiendo de la opción seleccionada del `select` tengo que enviar un dato diferente en el `input` al igual que tiene que entrar en una función.

```
<div class="select" *ngIf="bandcatalogonis" >
<select name="seleccion" id="op" (change)="Opciones($event.target.value)">
<option value="1" id="opts">ID</option>
<option value="2" id="opts">Nis</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Buscar" id="buc" (click)="buscar()">
```

Cree una función dónde valido que opción se seleccionó:

```
 Opciones(opc) {
    //console.log(opc);
    if(opc == '1'){
      console.log("ID 1");
    }else if(opc == '2'){
      console.log("ID 2");
    }else if(opc == '3'){
      console.log("Perimetro");
    }else if(opc  == '4'){
      console.log("X");
    }
```

El problema esta en que que cuando envió el dato solo entra en una función, no e podido hacer que mediante la opción seleccionada se envié un dato diferente y entre en diferente funciones:

```
buscar() {
    if (this.dos === null) {
      this.bandnisnull = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.bandnisnull = false;
      }, 2100);
    } else {      
      this.buscarClaveCat();
      this.bandtabla1 = false;
      this.bandtablaclavecat2 = true;
    }
}
```

Alguna sugerencia por favor.

Comment: Hola Luis, te sugiero que mejores el título de tu pregunta, tal como está actualmente no dice nada acerca del problema.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para tu problema utilice ReactiveForms, aun que si estas usando [Material Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) se pudiera hacer como lo planteas tu usando `(selectionChange)="opc($event)"`, como no vi que lo empleabas no me fui por esa opcion, tampoco use la opcion de `NgModel` `ngModelChange` por que normalmente angular manda advertencia de que pronto se dejara usar.

lo primero crea una variable de tipo `FormControl`

```js
  selected: FormControl = new FormControl(null);
```

la ventaja en este caso de `ReactiveForms` es que nos permite tener un `Observable` del input y los cambios que este presente.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selected.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
      this.Opciones(changes);
    });
  }
```

Agregamos el vinculo `[formControl]="selected"`.

```html
<div class="select">
    <select name="seleccion" id="op" [formControl]="selected">
      <option value="null" id="opts">None</option>
      <option value="1" id="opts">ID</option>
      <option value="2" id="opts">Nis</option>  
    </select>
</div>
```

aca te dejo el ejemplo [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kkpanl?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Mediante el uso de la directiva **[(ngModel)]** podras obtener la opcion seleccionada en el **select**, Prueba esto:

Declara una variable en tu componente:

**tuComponente.ts**

```
seleccion:any;
```

**tuComponente.html**

```
<select name="select" [(ngModel)]="seleccion" name="op">
    <option value="1" selected>opcion 1</option>
    <option value="2">opcion 2</option>
  </select>

    <input type="text" [placeholder]="seleccion">
```

*Como puedes ver, puedes obtener el valor que se haya seleccionado en el select, y utilizarlo segun tus necesidades. Espero haberte acercado a la solucion del problema.*